# stop automatic sending request in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

I use get method to send request but after some time before getting response it sends another request automatically. Is there any way to stop sending request automatically or send request after completion of first request?

My script

```
$http.get('/products/_exports').success(function (data) {
    myWindow = window.open('../products/_exports','_parent');
    myWindow.close();
});
```

Comment: Can I have a look at the specific code you are using?

Comment: This resending request is not done by node but by your browser. You can try this by using cURL that does not reissue the request after some time.

Comment: Bring some more context to the table...

Comment: I also got this problem and is very annoying during debug. I couldn't figure out who resend the request which happens every 2 minutes. I believe it's node or express because I never experienced it in IIS. This is my first node project though.